# Diagnosing LCD backlight inverter problem

Tags: lcd, inverter

I am having problems diagnosing the error with a notebook LCD display inverter.

**Symptoms:** After switching the notebook on, the LCD backlight comes on but the intensity oscillates rapidly (flickers). After about 1 second the backlight turns off completely. Once the backlight has turned off, the AC output of the inverter measured with a DVM is 0 Vac.

I visually checked the inverter board and there are no obvious faults.

Given the symptoms, can anybody venture a guess at the problem?

- On the one hand I am tempted to say that the backlight is ok (after all it ignites) and the problem is more likely to lie with the inverter.
- On the other hand I am wondering whether the flickering of the bulb (faulty bulb?) causes a open-circuit protection of the inverter to kick in after 1 second.

So in summary I am not quite sure whether the fault is more likely to lie with the bulb or the inverter.

Comment: Is the backlight a cold cathode fluorescent tube (CCFT)?

Comment: @JYelton I believe so but have not taken everything apart. CCFT is the standard for LCD notebook backlights however, no?

Comment: Repair questions are off-topic.

Comment: @LeonHeller Point taken. I have remove the repair component from the question and focused on the fault diagnosis procedure to make the question and its answers transferable to other situations with LCD backlight issues.

Comment: @Arik Not necessarily, there's also LED backlights, but they wouldn't require an inverter.

Comment: Please mention it is about a notebook LCD in your question.

Comment: @jippie I ammended the question as suggested.

Comment: any possibility of finding the service manual and the schematic of the inverter?

Answer (score 1):

Just be aware that there are potentially very high voltages on board the inverter.  Be careful.

It is entirely possible that you'll be able to find a replacement part from another laptop.  There are a few common suppliers that multiple manufacturers used.  Look to a laptop supply place in your area for leads and supplies.  Here I am referring to both the CCFL and the inverter.

Comment: Thanks for the warning about the high voltage. It is one of the reason why my fault-finding efforts were fairly rudimentary. I did not want to fry my DVM... Regarding replacement: Sumida is a very common supplier. My primary concern is that I do not know to what extent voltages and current requirements of backlights in different laptops are comparable. Also, as already mentioned, there is the issue of the 4 IO(?) pins.

Comment: @Arik You may want to look for a similar or exact model laptop with a cracked screen or dead motherboard, and see if you can extract working backlight parts from it.

Comment: @JYelton Good idea, unfortunately it is a rare model (about 1 on Ebay worldwide every few months). Maybe I will get lucky...

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to replacement. It's called fault isolation method in troubleshooting. However this could not be a final accepted answer. Because I mean it's all about symptoms and root cases.

Comment: Most probably this is due to electronic dieseling issue. 
I'm not aware of this, but http://www.electriciantalk.com/f2/fluorescent-bulbs-flicker-while-after-turned-off-9851/

Answer (score 0):

This issue sounds like either a failing backlight inverter, and/or failing CCFL's.  Either one can cause flickering and eventual halting of the inverter.

First, most multimeters will have a hard time measuring the high-voltage AC coming out of these inverters.  The reason why is because the frequency is very high, hundreds of kilohertz likely, and most meters just aren't capable of handling such a high frequency.  So they might misreport the actual voltage, or fail to give a solid reading... so just don't bother.  The volts are either there or they're not - they're never "low" and nothing could be done about it if it was.  A dim display is typically failing CCFL's. The only way to really "see" what the CCFL voltage is doing is with an oscilloscope and x100 probe.

If, when "on", the CCFL backlights appear orange-ish or pink-ish, then they are definitely failing. LED backlights will not do this, only CCFL's, and only some of the time.  But pink/orange/red = definitely failing.  And it might only be one CCFL; the other one(s) might be fine - but *one bad one* will affect all of them.

The easiest recourse is to swap the inverter with another working one ("Fault Isolation" as Standard Sandun calls it.)  If it does the exact same thing, it's likely the lamps.

The inverter probably has one or two large-ish electrolytic caps on it.  They can fail (without any visible indication) and replacing with equivalent low-ESR cap(s) could fix it.  Other inverters have a little controller chip on them and for whatever reason, they just decide to stop working... so if nothing on the inverter is damaged and changing the caps doesn't help, then it's scrap.

Now backlight inverters come in several sizes, shapes, and numbers of outputs.  Their connectors are also different on the various size boards, which makes them hard to troubleshoot (almost need an identical unit for a compatible spare.)  The *function* of those pins is *usually very similar* however, so if you can determine what pins do what on two different inverters, then you stand a good chance of being able to "hot-wire" a different unit in for testing.

Might have luck searching for the model number of the inverter on eBay - someone could have parted-out a similar unit.  Backlight inverters are kind-of like car parts - can find the same exact part in a variety of cars.  So that one might have came out of a small Daewoo TV - doesn't matter as long as it's the right model number.

Could also do the same with the display model numbers - get another one, and connect *those* CCFL's to *your* inverter, and try running it.  If the backlights stay on (nothing is displayed on it of course except the dim black but the backlights don't blink), then the backlights in your LCD are bad.  Many LCD's have removable backlight assemblies, which could be a fairly easy swap. But a few do not, and would require the entire LCD to be disassembled (not recommended.)  In that case, just swap the whole LCD.