# Electron Carbonization issue related to inductors and ballasts

Tags: inductor, ballast, ccfl

I have searched on the internet and I found nothing on this area. Not even a wiki
page, and not on several book glossaries.

This is related to the CCFL ballasts and inductors that used to control the current flow of gas discharge tubes. Also known as 'Electronic Dieseling' as described like this in [here](http://www.electriciantalk.com/f2/fluorescent-bulbs-flicker-while-after-turned-off-9851/).

> It's a phenomenon called "Electronic Dieseling". Its akin to turning
>   your car engine off and it continues to chug along for a few seconds.
>
> The solution is to completely disassemble the ballast and clean all
>   the electron carbonization from between the windings. Reassemble the
>   ballast, being sure to dull any sharp bends of the electron flow
>   pipes. Then when restarting, make sure you use an hertzane electron
>   additive to raise the electrons sparkrtronic flash point. This should
>   prevent future events of electronic dieseling...

But the content is not so clear. How that happens and what electro-chemistry is behind this.

This is also a possible case scenario for this question: [Diagnosing LCD backlight inverter problem](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/52769/diagnosing-lcd-backlight-inverter-problem)

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure if you are asking a serious question, but the inclusion is just a  bit of silliness. While there are problems in the current design of commercial (mostly from China) CFL Ballasts, "Electronic Dieseling" is not one of them.
In other words, it is a joke article.

Comment: are you serious sir that this is NOT serious?
So there's nothing called 'electronic Dieseling

Answer (score 3):

Note all of the smiley faces associated with that answer (and the responses to it)? It's a joke, not meant to be taken seriously.